# Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?

Tags: java, отладка, обработка-ошибок, java-faq

При написании кода он, порой, не работает так, как я задумал или не работает в принципе. Я сижу и гадаю: что и где не так?

Немного посмотрев на код - иду на ресурсы профессионалов, например *Stack Overflow* и публикую вопрос  *"Где здесь ошибка?"* или *"Почему не работает?"*

В итоге очень часто проблема мелкая: дурацкая опечатка, ошибка в синтаксисе и подобное. Профессионалом так не стать, если по каждой мелочёвке бегать по ресурсам. А я хочу им быть.

**Вопрос**: какие есть способы, чтобы найти ошибки в *Java* коде? Какие есть инструменты, методы, пути и пр.?

Comment: Поддерживаю одного из коментаторов, Алексей, Вам бы книжки писать! Уверен читатели бы нашлись.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Вчера всё работало, а сегодня не работает / Код не работает как задумано

или

## Debugging (Отладка)

---

В чем заключается процесс отладки? Что это такое?

**Процесс отладки состоит в том, что мы останавливаем выполнения скрипта в любом месте, смотрим, что находится в переменных, в функциях, анализируем и переходим в другие места; ищем те места, где поведение отклоняется от правильного.**

*Заметка:* Отладка производится как правило в **IDE (Интегрированная среда разработки)**. Что это такое можно чуть подробнее ознакомиться в вопросе

#### [Какие есть способы предупреждения ошибок, их нахождения и устранения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701818/191482)

В данном случае будет рассмотрен пример с *Intellij IDEA*, но отладить код можно и в любой другой *IDE*.

---

### **Подготовка**

Достаточно иметь в наличии *IDE*, например *Intellij IDEA*

### **Запуск**

Для начала в левой части панели с кодом на любой строке можно кликнуть <kbd>ЛКМ</kbd>, тем самым поставив точку останова (breakpoint - брейкпойнт). Это то место, где отладчик автоматически остановит выполнение *Java*, как только до него дойдёт. Количество breakpoint'ов не ограничено. Можно ставить везде и много.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отладка запускается сочетанием <kbd>Shift+F9</kbd> или выбором в верхнем меню `Run` → `Debug` или нажатием зеленого "жучка":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случае, т.к. функция вызывается сразу на той же странице, то при нажатии кнопки `Debug` — отладчик моментально вызовет метод, выполнение "заморозится" на первом же брейкпойнте. В ином случае, для активации требуется исполнить действие, при котором произойдет исполнение нужного участка кода (клик на кнопку в UI, передача POST запроса с данными и прочие другие действия)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цифрами обозначены:

1. Стэк вызовов, все вложенные вызовы, которые привели к текущему месту кода.
2. Переменные. На текущий момент строки ниже номера 24 ещё не выполнилась, поэтому определена лишь `data` и `numsStringArr`
3. Показывает текущие значения любых переменных и выражений. В любой момент здесь можно нажать на `+`, вписать имя любой переменной и посмотреть её значение в реальном времени. Например `data` или `nums[0]`, а можно и `nums[i]` и `item.test.data.name[5].info[key[1]]` и т.д. На текущий момент строки ниже номера 24 ещё не выполнилась, поэтому `sum` и `output` во вкладке `Watchers` обозначены красным цветом с надписью "cannot find local variable".

### **Процесс**

Для самого процесса используются **элементы управления** (см. изображение выше, выделено зеленым прямоугольником) и немного из **дополнительно** (см. изображение выше, выделено оранжевым прямоугольником)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Show Execution Point (<kbd>Alt+F10</kbd>) — переносит в файл и текущую линию отлаживаемого скрипта. Например если файлов много, решили посмотреть что в других вкладках, а потом забыли где у вас отладка :)

Step Over (<kbd>F8</kbd>) — делает один шаг не заходя внутрь функции. Т.е. если на текущей линии есть какая-то функция, а не просто переменная со значением, то при клике данной кнопки, отладчик не будет заходить внутрь неё.

Step Into (<kbd>F7</kbd>) —  делает шаг. Но в отличие от предыдущей, если есть вложенный вызов (например функция), то заходит внутрь неё.

Step Out (<kbd>Shift+F8</kbd>) — выполняет команды до завершения текущей функции. Удобна, если случайно вошли во вложенный вызов и нужно быстро из него выйти, не завершая при этом отладку.

Rerun (<kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd>) — Перезапустить отладку

Resume Program(<kbd>F9</kbd>) — Продолжает выполнения скрипта с текущего момента. Если больше нет других точек останова, то отладка заканчивается и скрипт продолжает работу. В ином случае работа прерывается на следующей точке останова.

Stop (<kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd>) — Завершить отладку

View Breakpoints (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F8</kbd>) — Посмотреть все установленные брейкпойнты

Mute Breakpoints — Отключить брейкпойнты.

...

Итак,  в текущем коде видно значение входного параметра:

- `data = "23 24 11 18"` —  строка с данными через пробел
- `numsStringArr = {"23", "24", "11", "18"}` — массив строк, который получился из входной переменной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нажмем <kbd>F8</kbd> 2 раза, то окажемся на строке 27; во вкладках `Watches` и `Variables` и в самой странице с кодом увидим, что переменная `sum` была инициализирована и значение равно 0, а также `nums` инициализирована и в ней лежит массив целых чисел `{23, 24, 11, 18}` .

Если теперь нажмем <kbd>F8</kbd>, то попадем внутрь цикла `for` и нажимая теперь <kbd>F8</kbd> пока не окончится цикл, можно будет наблюдать на каждой итерации, как значение `num` и `sum` постоянно изменяются. Тем самым мы можем проследить шаг за шагом весь процесс изменения любых переменных и значений на любом этапе, который интересует.

Дальнейшие нажатия <kbd>F8</kbd> переместит линию кода на строки 31, 32 и, наконец, 36.

---

### **Дополнительно**

Если нажать на `View Breakpoints` в левой панели, то можно не только посмотреть все брейкпойнты, но в появившемся окно можно еще более тонко настроить условие, при котором на данной отметке надо остановиться. В методе выше, например, нужно остановиться только когда `sum` превысит значение 20.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это удобно, если останов нужен только при определённом значении, а не всегда (особенно в случае с циклами).

Больше информации об отладке можно посмотреть в http://learn.javajoy.net/debug-intellij-idea, а также в официальной документации к *IDE*

Answer (score 11):

Алексей всё правильно написал, но по доброте своей допустил некоторое упрощение, которое я сейчас постараюсь исправить.

**IDE не обязательна как для разработки, так и для отладки!** 
(Можете быть уверены, в этом месте я зловеще захохотал)

Исходный код можно писать в любом текстовом редакторе, а компиляцию и отладку можно осуществлять консольными утилитами JDK. Для большей ̶ ̶г̶р̶о̶т̶е̶с̶к̶н̶о̶с̶т̶и̶   восхитительности происходящего будем считать, что работа осуществляется под управлением Windows 7 x64.

Прежде всего, для удобства использования инструментов JDK, [добавим их в переменную окружения PATH](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml). А чтобы в полной мере пройти тропой древних, исходный текст будем писать не выходя из консоли. Запускаем командную строку `cmd`, набираем `copy con App.java`, вводим код и нажимаем <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для компиляции вводим команду `javac -g App.java`. Ключ `-g` нужен для включения отладочной информации в class-файл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И наконец запускаем отладчик командой `jdb App`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на скриншоте, первым делом я установил точку останова на метод main командой `stop on App.main` и запустил выполнение командой `run`. Отладчик, в соответствии с точкой останова, остановил выполнение на 8-й строке программы и показал её.

Аналогично командам доступным в IDE можно:

- Посмотреть текущую позицию отладки командой `list`
- Выполнить следующую строку командой `step`
- "Перешагнуть" вызов метода командой `next`
- "Шагнуть" из метода командой `step up`
- Вернуться к выполнению программы командой `cont`
- Вывести список локальный переменных командой `locals` или вывести значение какой-либо конкретной переменной командой `print <имя переменной>`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Самая полезная команда - это `help` или `?`, позволяющая получить справку по всем командам. И конечно же команда без которой не обойтись - `quit`.

Comment: Ну во-первых в моём ответе **нет** текста "обязательно делается в IDE", там написано **как правило**.... Так что ваш хохот довольно по странной причине..... Ну а в целом отлаживать программу в консоли. А вы извращенец, мистер)) Это конечно можно, но чертовски неудобно. Я бы ни за что не стал это делать ни как новичок, ни как человек с опытом для которого важно удобство, быстрота и наличие вменяемых инструментов доступа)) Но спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Хохот у меня по причине того, что многие вопрошающие не только не хотят пользоваться отладчиком, но и живут в уверенности, что за пределами IDE холодный космос. В повседневной жизни я тоже пользуюсь IDE, но знать, что там под капотом - это в целом полезно, а для специалиста важно. Поэтому не мог не дополнить вашу восхитительную публикацию. Пусть сегодня будет день открытий для множества _молодых специалистов_.

Comment: `что там под капотом - это в целом полезно` - это да, согласен.