# Java программа выдает ошибку

Tags: java

Пишу код он выводит папки и подпапки после ввода директории, откуда начинать поиск. Так вот, иногда Netbeans выдает ошибку:

```
*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pro.kkk.file.DetectFolder.setPathBuffer(DetectFolder.java:15)
    at pro.kkk.file.DetectFolder.setPathBuffer(DetectFolder.java:18)
    at pro.kkk.file.DetectFolder.setPathBuffer(DetectFolder.java:18)
    at PointIn.main(PointIn.java:15)
C:\Users\Best\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 9 секунды)*
```

Когда выдает и при каких обстоятельствах я понять не могу. вводишь один каталог нормально все, другой эта ошибка выскакивает!

```
import java.io.File;
import pro.kkk.file.DetectFolder;
import pro.kkk.input.Input;

public class PointIn {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Input in = new Input();
        in.read();
        System.out.println("Ведем поиск от каталога " + in.catalog);

        DetectFolder df = new DetectFolder();
        File folder = new File(in.catalog);
        df.setPathBuffer(folder);
    }

}



package pro.kkk.file;

import java.io.File;

public class DetectFolder {

    private String[] pathBuffer;
    public String[] getPathBuffer(){
        return pathBuffer;
    }

    public void setPathBuffer(File folder){
        File[] f = folder.listFiles();
        for (File i : f){
            if (i.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println(i);
                setPathBuffer(i);
            }
        }
    }

}




package pro.kkk.input;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Input {
   public String catalog;


    public void read(){
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите директорию: ");
        catalog = read.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Будь программистом: Возьми отладчик и пройдись им и посмотри при каких обстоятельствах выдает ошибку!..... Во-первых вот тебе об отладке ссылка  **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/191482)**, а вот в целом про NPE **[Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/511085/191482)**

Comment: В общем разобрался, не было доступа к папке, а так спасибо за ссылку) буду познавать))