# Java nio select() не блокирует поток

Tags: java, сервер, блокировки, nio2

Есть сервер (однопоточный nio) работающий с клиентами, все работает корректно кроме того, что после первого ответа клиенту метод select перестает блокировать поток (в котором был вызван), но все продолжает работать, а процессор загружен на максимум (причем при дебаге все работает).

Создается ServerSocketChannel так:

```
Selector selector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
ServerSocketChannel serverChanel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverChanel.configureBlocking(false);
serverChanel.register(selector, serverChanel.validOps());
serverChanel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(lisenHost, listenPort));

while(true) {

selector.select(); //С какого-то момента не блокирует и как правило возвращает 0

Iterator<SelectionKey> selectionKeys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                logger.debug(selectionKeys.hasNext());
...
```

Присоединение клиента происходит так

```
SocketChannel socketChannel = ((ServerSocketChannel) key.channel()).accept();
socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
socketChannel.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_READ);
```

Если сам сервер куда-то конектится это происходит так:

```
SocketChannel hostSocket = SocketChannel.open();
hostSocket.configureBlocking(false);
hostSocket.register(key.selector(), SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
hostSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port));
```

...

```
if (key.isConnectable()) {
((SocketChannel) key.channel()).finishConnect();
key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);
}
```

Когда надо что-то записать слушаю `SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE`.

После записи выполняю `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)`
И после выполнения операции на запись select() перестает блокировать (если заменить `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)` на `key.interestOps(0)`, то select() остается блокирующим).
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Покажите код регистрации в селекторе принятых соединений.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev
Вопрос по поводу вашего ответа.
Что если я хочу продолжать использовать ключ, а не закрывать его `key.cancel()`?

Comment: По идее, должно работать `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)` или `key.interestOps(key.interestOps() & ~SelectionKey.OP_WRITE)`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Я так и делаю `key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ)`

Comment: Наверняка есть какой-то неявный мешающий фактор. Боюсь, что обнаружить его можно только [прогнав программу под отладчиком](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/204271) и посмотрев, какие именно каналы и в каком именно состоянии попадают в селектор, когда он перестаёт блокироваться.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Под отладкой как выяснилось все работает (хоть программа и однопоточная)

Comment: Гейзенбаг, однако!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Если после в методе `write` добавить `Thread.sleep(100)` то все работает.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Все работает, баг состоял в том что я пытался писать в еще не законекченный канал

Answer (score 1):

`select()` возвращает 0 в том случае, когда зарегистрированные в селекторе сокеты перешли в состояние готовности ещё до вызова `select()`.

Скорее всего проблема связана с тем, что сокеты всегда готовы к записи, если ваш сервер не генерирует поток данных полностью исчерпывающий пропускную способность сетевого интерфейса. Поэтому регистрировать сокет с `OP_WRITE` стоит только тогда, когда вам есть, что в него писать, а после вызывать `key.cancel()`.

И небольшая рекомендация: Поменяйте порядок следования вызовов `bind` и `register`. Регистрировать в селекторе стоит только уже открытые соединения.