# вызвать метод, который меняет цвет edittext через некоторое время

Tags: java, android, android-studio, многопоточность

делаю выделение синтаксиса текста в Android Studio, для этого мне нужен таймер, который каждые 5 секунд будет вызывать метод проверки синтаксиса, в свою очередь, этот метод получает сам `EditText` и обрабатывает его. Пробовал через `ScheduledExecutorService`, но почему-то программа зависает во время выполнения метода. Вот код, как я делал в отдельном потоке:

```
class synLight implements Runnable {

    private EditText editText;

    public synLight(EditText editText){
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws RuntimeException{
        MainActivity.editText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)

```
int interval = 5000;
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // Необходимые действия          

      handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
    }
});
```

Comment: у меня метод, который нужно выполнить через некоторое время берёт на вход EditText, как тогда быть?

Comment: Не вижу проблемы, анонимные классы могут использовать переменные объемлющей области видимости.

Comment: Текст почему-то не меняется( Только один раз проверился, а дальше не хочет.

Comment: Если ошибок нет, но программа не работает так, как надо, то [придётся использовать отладчик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/204271).

Comment: спасибо тебе) а handler и interval должны быть final? Просто компилятор выдавал ошибку.

Comment: По идее должно хватать и effectively final, но лишним явное указание модификатора не будет.

Comment: Спасибо большое))) 5 дней с этим возился)