# Какой символ использует DecimalFormat вместо пробела?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь убрать пробелы из строки, но ничего не происходит.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 66;
        int j = 66;
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
        format.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(false);

        String s = String.valueOf(format.format(i*j )).replaceAll("\\s", "");

        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
    }
}
```

ошибка

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4 356"

    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

с чем это связано и как убрать этот псевдопробел? 
PS: если написать просто строку с пробелом `replaceAll` работает нормально

Comment: В чем проблема открыть дебагер и посмотреть?

Comment: да без проблем, только вопрос как?)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все потому, что тот пробел, который появляется в результате `format` является неразрывным, его код в ASCII таблице равен 160, что в шестнадцатеричной системе исчисления соответствует A0.

Вы можете использовать следующий regexp:

```
String s = String.valueOf(format.format(i*j )).replaceAll("\u00a0", "");
```

Будьте внимательны, что при форматировании дробного числа, точка скорее всего будет заменена на запятую (зависит от локали), что также не даст распарсить это число. Чтобы исправить эту проблему, вы можете либо в методе `replaceAll` заменить запятую на точку, либо использовать `DecimalFormatSymbols`:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols formatSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
formatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(formatSymbols);
```

---

В вашем случае, так как вы умножаете целые числа и произведение всегда будет целым достаточно даже простого `\\D`:

```
String s = String.valueOf(format.format(i*j )).replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

> "\D" - Соответствует любому нецифровому символу. Эквивалентно выражению [^0-9].

Будьте внимательны, что при форматировании дробных чисел, точка в этом случае будет стерта.