# Null Pointer Exception при получение переменной из другого модуля

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

У меня есть 2 модуля

первый хранит коллекцию id

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/category/")
public class CategoryController {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    List<Long> id = categoryService.getAllIds();
```

во 2 мне надо получить это значение

```
   List<Long> id = categoryController.id;
```

Но почему то выбрасывает

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause. Не знаю в чем проблема Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но почему то выбрасывает null pointer exception

Потому, что (на выбор варианты):

1. `categoryService` не присвоено значение
2. в `categoryService` не присвоено значение переменой `id`
3. `getAllIds()` возвращает `null`

java.lang.NullPointerException означает, что вы пытаетесь получить данные из переменной, значение которой не присвоено либо == null.

*И не нужно плодить одни и те же вопросы. Из той информации что вы предоставили больше ничего и никто вам не скажет. Пройдитесь дебагом по всей цепочке и найдёте проблему. За вас это никто не сделает.*

Comment: Да я включил дебаг, но оно выдает ошибки вообще в сторонних классах типа httpservlet, и это не даёт никакой зацепки на решение

Comment: @АртёмКурилко Дебаг не выдаёт ошибки. Вы видимо включили лог, а не дебаг. Вот тут отлично всё расписано по дебагу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/Как-и-какими-средствами-находить-ошибки-в-коде-java

Comment: `данные из переменной, значение которой не присвоено`, не примитивные типы в Java - относятся к ссылочным, поэтому хранят не значение, а ссылку на адрес объекта в памяти.