# Выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class StartKalc {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int answer;
    Reshenie res = new Reshenie();
    KalcRim kalcRim = new KalcRim();

    ArrayList<String> krim = kalcRim.kalcRim();
    ArrayList<Integer> karab = kalcRim.kalcArab();

    public void startKalc() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // считываем с консоли
        String s = bufferedReader.readLine();  // помещаем в строку
        String[] character = s.split(" "); // преобразование строки в массив строк с исключением пробелов
        String sumbol = character[1];


        System.out.println(krim.get(4)); // проверял что массив подключился из другого класса


        if(krim.contains(character[0])) {

            for (String reader : character/*int j = 0; j < 3; j++*/) {
                int index = krim.indexOf(reader);
                System.out.println(index); // проверял что массив подключился из другого класса
                int get = karab.get(index);

                try {
                    System.out.println(list); // проверка что массив создан и пуст
                    System.out.println(get); // проверка что переменная правильна
                    list.add(get); // вот здесь выпадает ошибка

                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {  // пробрасываем исключения
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        else {
            for (String reader : character) {  // преобразование строк в числа типа Integer
                try {
                    int q = Integer.parseInt(reader);
                    list.add(q);
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {  // пробрасываем исключения
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        int x = list.get(0); //присваеваем переменным числа из массива
        int y = list.get(1);

        String r = sumbol;
        
        answer = res.resh(x, y, r); // перелаем на вычисление

        System.out.println("Otvet " + answer);

    }
}
```

вылетает ошибка при попытке добавить элементы в list, в первом цикле for.

Comment: **[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java? (Отладка)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701413/191482)**

Comment: Какой тип у `character`? И почему вы его юзаете в качестве ключа тут `if(krim.containsKey(character))`?

Comment: да с character я там хорошо косякнул, исправил тот момент и выяснил где именно выдает ошибку, но причину понять не могу