# Поменять элементы массива местами

Tags: java

Дан массив, поменять местами 2-й и 5-й элемент. Не могу найти ошибку.

```
int nums[] = { 15, 63, 44, 14, 33, 36 };
        
        for (int t = 0; t < nums.length; t++)
            System.out.print(nums[t] + " ");
        System.out.println();
        
        int g;
        for (int t = 0; t < nums.length; t++) {
            g = nums[4]; 
            nums[4] = nums[1]; 
            nums[1] = g;
            System.out.print(nums[t] + " ");
        }
```

Comment: зачем вам потребовался цикл? зачем перебирать все элементы, если вы заране знаете, какие из них нужно поменять. а теперь получается, что вы в цикле меняете их какое-то количество раз. поскольку цикл с четным кол-вом элементов, эти множественные замены приводят массив к исходному виду

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Получается, мне нужно  g = nums[4]; nums[4] = nums[1]; nums[1] = g; эту часть убрать из цикла? Оно не приводит к исходному ввиду.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это относится к синтаксическим?

Comment: @SmaugDr к любым

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int g = nums[4]; 
nums[4] = nums[1]; 
nums[1] = g;
for (int t = 0; t < nums.length; t++) {
      System.out.print(nums[t] + " ");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно решить с помощью цикла?

Comment: Можно, но зачем усложнять?