# Как сравнить массив String на палиндром - Java

Tags: java

У меня есть код, сначала я ввожу массив с двух слов, потом в методе `wypisz` я выписываю
массив и + перевожу его в строку символов чтобы легче было сравнивать на палиндром, дальше
в методе `wypiszOdKonca` я делать все тоже самое что и в методе выше, но с конца вывожу
массив + тоже перевожу его в строку символов. Потом в методе `czyPalindrom` я с помощью
функции `equals` сравниваю строку символов нормально выведенную + строку символов
выведенную с конца, и если они совпадают то хочу вернуть `true`. Сейчас даже когда они
у меня одинаковые то я получаю `false`, не понимаю почему так.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tablica tablica = new Tablica(2);
        tablica.do_tablicy();
        tablica.wypisz();
        System.out.print("\n");
        tablica.wypiszOdKonca();
        System.out.print("\n" + tablica.czyPalindrom());
    }
```

```
public class Tablica {
    private int liczbaElementow;
    private String[] tablica;

    private String resultOdPoczatku = "";
    private String resultOdKonca = "";
    private char[] charArrayOdPoczatku;
    private char[] charArrayOdKonca;

    public Tablica(int liczbaElementow) {
        this.liczbaElementow = liczbaElementow;
        tablica = new String[liczbaElementow];
    }

    public void do_tablicy() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < tablica.length; i++)
            tablica[i] = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    public void wypisz() {
        for (String x : tablica) {
            System.out.print(x + "\t");
            resultOdPoczatku = resultOdPoczatku + x;
        }

        charArrayOdKonca = resultOdPoczatku.toCharArray();
        System.out.print(charArrayOdKonca);
    }

    public void wypiszOdKonca() {
        for (int i = tablica.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(tablica[i] + "\t");
            resultOdKonca = resultOdKonca + tablica[i];
        }

        charArrayOdPoczatku = resultOdKonca.toCharArray();
        System.out.print(charArrayOdPoczatku);
    }

    public boolean czyPalindrom() {
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print(charArrayOdPoczatku);
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print(charArrayOdKonca);

        return charArrayOdPoczatku.equals(charArrayOdKonca);
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: "даже когда они у меня одинаковые то я получаю false" - значит разные

Comment: @Igor я всегда получаю false

Comment: Вы неправильно используете .equals, здесь сравнивается совсем не то.

Comment: @VladyslavVerong Значит Ваши массивы - разные.

Comment: @Igor но предварительно я вывожу то что сравниваю, и даже когда оно идентично то все равно возвращает false

Comment: @VladyslavVerong Вы можете меня сколько угодно уговаривать. Я Вам не верю.

Comment: @ахахахахахахаха)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777266/6104996  .......... используй `Arrays.equals(array1, array2);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я задал вопрос на русской версии сайта, если вы не знаете как помочь, то не стоит писать комментарии на различные темы, мы здесь обсуждаем мою проблему, советую ознакомится с - (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: @VladyslavVerong То есть ты считаешь, что обсуждение верю-не верю - уместно, а сообщение чтобы ты использовал для сравнения `Arrays.equals(array1, array2);` - не уместным и не является тем, что поможет? Мда...)) Логике тебе не занимать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не будем перекладывать с больной головы на здоровую. Вы можете честно признаться, что не знаете, как помочь?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский так же рекомендую ознакомится с манерами общения в чате с другими участниками

Comment: @VladyslavVerong рекомендую ознакомится с понятием "чат" и где конкретно сейчас пишутся сообщения :))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский рекомендую вам научиться признавать поражения

Comment: @VladyslavVerong а что, сейчас какая-то битва происходит? О_о

Comment: "Но пораженья от победы ты сам не должен отличать." Пастернак

Comment: @АлексейШиманский примечательно, что комментарии в стиле "если не знаете, то не надо писать" или даже рекомендации научиться признавать поражения (щито???) пишут всегда именно те люди, которые не в состоянии решить элементарнейшую проблему даже после того, как им прямым текстом написали, как ее решить. Хрестоматийный пример эффекта Даннинга-Крюгера.

Answer (score 1):

В java проверка строки на палиндром легче всего осуществляется с помощью класса StringBuilder.
допустим есть строка "abcba"

```
String str = "abcba";
```

Тогда условие проверки будет:

```
str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
```