# Java Вызов метода

Tags: java, классы, double

Подскажите пожалуйста один момент. Я создаю объект класса многоугольник, вызываю метод и получаю результат на экране. Почему не отрабатывает метод с подсчетом площади треугольника?В чем проблема?

```
    class Polygon {
    int sideLengths[];
    int numSides =0;

    public Polygon(int [] lengths){
      sideLengths = lengths;
      numSides = lengths.length;
    }
  
    public int perimeter() {
  
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0 ; i <  sideLengths.length ;i++) {
        sum += sideLengths[i];
      }
      return sum;
    }

   
  }

   class Triangle extends Polygon {

    public Triangle(int [] lengths) {
      super(lengths);  
      numSides = 3;
    }
    public Triangle () {
      this(new int[3]);
    }
    

    public double area (){
      double s = perimeter()/2;
      //формула Герона
      return Math.sqrt(s*(s- sideLengths[0])*(s- sideLengths[1])*(s - sideLengths[2]));
    }
  }
public class ThirdLab {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] lengths = new int[]{2, 2, 3};
        Polygon test_polygon = new Polygon(lengths);
        double t = test_polygon.perimeter();
        
        int[] lengths1 = new int[]{2, 2, 3};
        Triangle triangle1 = new Triangle(lengths1);
        double t1 = triangle1.area();
        
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println(t1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Происходит ошибка или неправильный результат?

Comment: @gil9red Выводится нулевое значение.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Пробовали отладить код, например через `System.out.println` вывести код в `public double area (){`? Кст, уже тут вижу проблему `double s = perimeter()/2;` - у вас `perimeter` возвращает `int`, делите тоже на целое число, поэтому потеряется дробная часть, нужно или возвращать из `perimeter` вещественное число или делить на вещественное: `double s = perimeter() / 2.0;`

Comment: @gil9red да, в этом , как оказалось, и заключалась проблема..надо было делить на вещественное. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина проблемы была в потере вещественной части при выполнении:

```
double s = perimeter()/2;
```

Т.к. метод `perimeter` возвращал целое число и деление тоже было на целое число.

Варианты решения:

- Возвращать из `perimeter` вещественное число. Понадобится в классе `Polygon` поменять типы на вещественные в поле `sideLengths`, в параметре конструктора `lengths`, в методе `perimeter` (возвращаемое значение и у переменной `sum`)
- Делить на вещественное число:

  ```
  double s = perimeter() / 2.0;
  ```