# Код работает не cовсем корректно

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста с проблемой. У меня есть код работающий, но некорректно. Я пытаюсь в коллекциях создавать сначала людей (addNewPerson), а затем к тем людям добавить машину (addCarToPerson). Так же у меня есть проверка, если нет такой человека, то машина не добавляется. Суть в том, что когда я создаю человека его будет видно, но при создании машины у меня почему-то говорит, что такого человека не существует. В чем моя ошибка? Спасибо

```
package package_one;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

static Map<Person, List<Car>> map = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    addNewPerson(new Person(1, "Petro", 26));
    addCarToPerson(new Person(1, "Petro", 26), new Car("Audi", 1500, Car_Type.SUV));

    addNewPerson(new Person(2,"Marta", 21));
    addCarToPerson(new Person(2, "Marta", 21), new Car("Opel", 1100, Car_Type.SEDAN));

    printMap(map);
}

public static void addNewPerson(Person person) {
    map.put(person, new ArrayList<>());
}

public static void addCarToPerson(Person person, Car car) {
    if (map.containsKey(person)) {
        final List<Car> cars = map.get(person);
        cars.add(car);
        System.out.println(String.format("Car is added for person", car.getName(), person.getName()));
    } else {
        System.out.println("No such person " + person.getName());
    }
}

public static void deleteCarFromPerson(Person person, Car car) {
    if (map.containsKey(person)) {
        final List<Car> cars = map.get(person);
        cars.remove(car);
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.println("No such person: " + person.getName());
    }
}

public static void printMap(Map<Person, List<Car>> map) {
    final Set<Map.Entry<Person, List<Car>>> set = map.entrySet();
    for (Map.Entry<Person, List<Car>> entry : set) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":");
        final List<Car> cars = entry.getValue();
        for (Car car : cars) {
            System.out.println("\t" + car);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: У вас equals и hashCode методы в Person и Car переопределены?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Йомайо, они у меня отсутствовали. Спасибо)

Comment: @Ronald, именно так люди и запоминают зачем нужны эти методы) И что они нужны всегда и в том же Kotlin для их автогенерации даже отдельное ключевое слово есть)