# Как вывести методом массив который был создан в конструкторе класса

Tags: java

в конструкторе должен создаваться и инициализироваться массив, а метод должен вывести его на экран.
Код класса:

```
class Array{
       int n,li,lj;
       double a,z,x,k,min,max,sum,sa,c;
       double[][] arr = new double[li][lj];
       Array(){
            n=21;
            a = 4;
            z = 5;
            k = (5+1.2*n-(-10-2.5*n))/(0.5+n/20); 
            li = (int) k;
            lj = 2;
            x=-10-2.5*n;
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
               if(j%2==0){arr[i][j]=z;}
               else arr[i][j]=(Math.pow(z + Math.sqrt(z*x), 1.0/5))/(Math.pow(Math.E, x)+(Math.pow(a, 5)*Math.atan(x)));
               if (Double.isNaN(arr[i][j])){arr[i][j]=0;} 
           }  
           x+=0.5+n/20;z+=0.5+n/20;a+=0.5+n/20;
           } 
       }
      void displayArray(){
           System.out.println("Array is:");
           for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
           System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "\t");
       }
       System.out.println();   
       }
       }
}
```

у меня сложным образом создаётся массив но он рабочий я его отдельно проверял, когда просто в мейне делал. а когда я его создаю в конструкторе и вывожу методом displayArray() у меня почему-то не выводит. я понимаю что создавать статичный массив для всего класса это не очень хорошо и лучше его не в конструкторе генерировать, но мне сейчас нужно так.
в мейне создавал объект класса так:

```
public class JavaApplication5 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array undef = new Array();
        undef.displayArray();
    }
}
```

Подскажите что я не так делаю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: В коде ошибки чтобы он не компилировался нет. У меня код вместо строки Array is: и массив выводит только Array is: без массива

Comment: В дубле написано как дебажить код. Прочитайте и сделайте

Comment: Скорее всего массив нулевой, т.к. он инициализируется за счёт li, lj, а они по дефолту 0 при создании класса

Comment: да всё верно я не доглядел

Comment: если размерность массива инициализировать не в конструкторе то всё будет хорошо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была найдена. Массив был нулевым и размерность нужно было объявить не в конструкторе.

Рабочий код выглядит так:

```
class Array{
    //int n;
    double a,z,x,min,max,sum,sa,c;  
    int lj = 2;
    int n=21;
    double k = (5+1.2*n-(-10-2.5*n))/(0.5+n/20); 
    int li = (int) k;
    double[][] arr = new double[li][lj];
    double[] m = new double[li];
    double[] m1 = new double[li];
    Array(){       
         a = 4;
         z = 5;
         x=-10-2.5*n;
         for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
            if(j%2==0){arr[i][j]=z;}
            else arr[i][j]=(Math.pow(z + Math.sqrt(z*x), 1.0/5))/(Math.pow(Math.E, x)+(Math.pow(a, 5)*Math.atan(x)));
            if (Double.isNaN(arr[i][j])){arr[i][j]=0;} 
        }  
        x+=0.5+n/20;z+=0.5+n/20;a+=0.5+n/20;
        } 
    }
}
```