# Код не выводит в консоль необходимые данные

Tags: java

Код должен выводить данные в соответствии с примером:

> Пример при вводе 2
> Грузовик: 1
> Контейнер: 1
> Ящик: 1
> Ящик: 2
> Необходимо:
> грузовиков - 1 шт.
> контейнеров - 1 шт.

Сейчас код выводит только часть "необходимо" с нулевыми значениями, игнорируя формулы.

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    int trucks = 0;
    int containers = 0;
    int box = 0;


    if (box != 0) {
        containers = box % 27 == 0 ? box / 27 : box / 27 + 1;
    }
    if (containers != 0) {

        trucks = containers % 12 == 0 ? containers / 12 : containers / 12 + 1;
    }


        int b = 1;
        int c = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= trucks; i++) {
            System.out.println("Грузовик: " + i);
            int x = 0;

            while (x < 12 && c <= containers) {

                System.out.println("\t Контейнер: " + c);
                int y = 0;
                while (y < 27 && b <= box) {
                    System.out.println("\t\t Ящик: " + b);
                    y++;
                    b++;
                }
                x++;
                c++;
            }
            System.out.println();


        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String boxes = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Необходимо:\n " + "грузовиков - " + trucks + " шт.\n" + "контейнеров - " + containers + " шт.");




}
```

}

Comment: удивительно. в самом начале кода объявлены переменные со значениями 0 и нигде не меняются. Чего вы тогда ожидаете - не ясно)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Поставте блок на ту часть кода которая работает и ищите ошибку кода который не работает пробуя выодить строку за строкой.

Comment: А где, собственно, вводятся значения?