# Кто может объяснить, почему берется наибольшее число массива? java

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[] {123, -39, 0, -783, 915, 102, -199};
    int b = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(b < a[i])
            b = a[i];
    }
    System.out.print(b);
    }
}
```

Недавно начал учить java и это мой первый язык. Кто может объяснить почему b принимает значение 915, а не -199?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Предлагаю вам ознакомиться с такой вещью, как отладка. И самостоятельно пройти по коду и увидеть что на каждой строчке происходит и на каждой итерации цикла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Условный оператор `if(b < a[i])`, расположенный в цикле, проверяет исходное число `b` с каждым элементом массива `a` (перебор осуществляется с помощью вышеупомянутого цикла). В том случае, если число `b` оказывается меньше очередного элемента массива, то оно становится равным данному элементу.

Отсюда, в частности, следует, что рано или поздно попадётся такой элемент `a[N]`, после которого данное условие ни разу не будет соблюдаться. Тогда мы можем сказать, что `a[N]` — максимальный элемент данного массива, и он рано или поздно попадёт в `b`.

Таким образом, если мы берём `b`, то данная переменная будет изменяться только тогда, когда очередной элемент массива будет больше. Рано или поздно `b` будет равно максимуму массива, поэтому с помощью данного алгоритма мы можем найти максимум массива. В данном случае максимумом будет `915`, поэтому именно это число и будет в `b`.

(Кстати говоря, лучше было бы, если `b` изначально было бы равно `a[0]`, а не `0`. Вдруг все элементы массива были бы отрицательными?).

P.S. Если заменить знак в условии с `<` на `>`, то тогда алгоритм вычислял бы, наоборот, минимальный элемент массива и занёс бы в `b` число `-199`.

Как-то так, кажется