# Доступ к переменной в условии IF внутри цикла FOR

Tags: java, циклы, if, область-видимости

Нужно переменной `companyNumber` присвоить значение итерации i, чтобы потом ее вывести вне цикла.  Получается, что переменная companyNumber видна в цикле, но после условия, результат присвоения не виден извне. Сейчас при печати - просто 0, значение которое было присвоено при объявлении переменной. Возможно как либо сделать ее доступной?

```
package HomeWork;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

    class Test1 {
       
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            // write your code here
            int companyNumber = 0;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            int[] yearlyIncome = new int[n];
            int[] tax = new int[n];
    
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                yearlyIncome[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
    
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                tax[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            double maxIncome = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                double income = yearlyIncome[i] * tax[i] / 100;
                if (income > maxIncome) {
                   maxIncome = income;
                  companyNumber =i;
                }
    
            }
            System.out.println(companyNumber);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: если речь идёт о `companyNumber` значит в условие не заходит. смотри по отладке что не так

Comment: Стоит проинициализировать `companyNumber = -1;` -- тогда будет видно, выполнилось ли условие `income > maxIncome` хотя бы раз.

Answer (score 1):

До цикла объявляешь, как и все переменные:

```
int i = 0;
```

Потом в цикле применяешь.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

---

если речь идёт о `companyNumber` значит в условие не заходит. смотри по отладке что не так

Смотри: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Спасибо! Поправил немного вопрос. Не то имел ввиду. Мне нужно поймать за хвост значение переменной i на котором income > maxIncome и затем вывести это значение на экран.  Значение должно выводится один раз, хотя по факту таких совпадений в цикле может быть много.

Comment: В условие должно заходить в любом случае.  По условиям задачи эти переменные yearlyIncome[i]  tax[i]  больше 0. Те по любому income должен получиться больше 0. Для того, чтобы там все работало переменная income double типа

Comment: Попробуй отладку и посмотри точно, заходит или нет. И там же сможешь посмотреть в какие моменты заходит и что присваивается

Comment: Все разобрался. Действительно вcе отрабатывало с переменными.  Надо было всего лишь к 100 добавить D 100D. Вот тут не знал. 

Спасибо за наводку!