# Вложенные условные конструкции Java

Tags: java

Всем привет, не выходит правильно не могу понять почему. Заранее спасибо

```
import java.lang.Math;
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt(), z = sc.nextInt(), y = sc.nextInt();
        int max1 = Math.max(x,z), max2 = Math.max(z,y);
        int min1 = Math.min(x,z), min2 = Math.min(z,y);
        if (max1 >= max2 || max1 <= max2){
            System.out.println("Ура, бастуем!");
        }else (min1 >= min2 || min1 <= min2){
            System.out.println("За работу, Солнце ещё высоко");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}



Формат ввода:

В первой строке - зарплаты разработчиков через пробел, три целых числа.

Во второй строке - разница, при превышении которой будет объявлена забастовка.

Формат вывода:

"Ура, бастуем!" - если критический уровень превышен;

"За работу, Солнце ещё высоко" - если критический уровень не превышен.

Sample Input:

300 400 500
100
Sample Output:

Ура, бастуем!
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Кроме опечатки `else if`, в данном коде есть логическая ошибка, так как условие первого `if` будет выполняться **всегда**: `max1 >= max2 || max1 <= max2` -- из двух чисел **всегда** одно будет меньше или равно другому.

Answer (score 2):

У вас условие после оператора **else**, а условие должно быть только после оператора **if**. Попробуйте так:

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt(), z = sc.nextInt(), y = sc.nextInt();
        int max1 = Math.max(x,z), max2 = Math.max(z,y);
        int min1 = Math.min(x,z), min2 = Math.min(z,y);
        if (max1 >= max2 || max1 <= max2){
            System.out.println("Ура, бастуем!");
        }else  if (min1 >= min2 || min1 <= min2){
            System.out.println("За работу, Солнце ещё высоко");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

или так (в зависимости от задачи)

```
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt(), z = sc.nextInt(), y = sc.nextInt();
        int max1 = Math.max(x,z), max2 = Math.max(z,y);
        int min1 = Math.min(x,z), min2 = Math.min(z,y);
        if (max1 >= max2 || max1 <= max2){
            System.out.println("Ура, бастуем!");
        }if (min1 >= min2 || min1 <= min2){
            System.out.println("За работу, Солнце ещё высоко");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Кроме опечатки `else if`, в данном коде есть логическая ошибка, так как условие первого `if` будет выполняться **всегда**: `max1 >= max2 || max1 <= max2` -- из двух чисел **всегда** одно будет меньше или равно другому.