# Не понимаю логику цикла for в выведении треугольника в java

Tags: java, for

Хочу понять, как работает цикл for в следующем коде:

```
for (int line = 8; line > 0; line--) { 
       for (int gap = line; gap > 0; gap--)  
        System.out.print(" "); 
       for (int point = line; point < 9; point++)  
       System.out.print(".."); 
      System.out.println(); 
      }
```

Здесь в консоль будет выводиться равнобедренный треугольник с вершиной вверх. Но почему, если в переменная point имеет значение line, то есть 8. Разве в первой строке не должно появиться 16 точек? Почему 16 точек появятся только в конце, в основании треугольника?

Comment: почему в отладке не посмотреть все значения и почему это как считается?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Каким образом при `line == 8` цикл `for (int point = 8; point < 9; point++) System.out.print("..");` должен выполниться больше одного раза?

Comment: @wololo ну так в следующем такте цикла значение line вроде бы как будет на 1 меньше... Хотя, конечно, может быть, я ошибаюсь и чего-то не знаю

Comment: @АлексейШиманский об отладке не знал. Спасибо за совет, сейчас посмотрю.

Comment: `в следующем такте цикла значение line вроде бы как будет на 1 меньше` будет. К тому моменту, когда это произойдёт, вывод первой строки треугольника будет завершён.