# как искать ошибки в гугле ? Java

Tags: java, обработка-ошибок

Всем привет, в языке Java я новенькая ( относительно) изучаю всего каких то пол года, читала книги, смотрела Ютуб, Гугл, курсы на скиллбокс проходила, а вот исправлять ошибки в коде я не научилась.  Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно гуглить?

Comment: универсальных механизмов, имхо, нет......но как минимум один подход есть: если написан текст ошибки, то его и надо вбивать в поисковике с указанием языка: например: "java IndexOutOfBoundsException".

Comment: К комментарию выше, можно добавлять "ошибка", чтобы результаты в первую очередь на русском выходили: "java ошибка IndexOutOfBoundsException". Если так ничего похожего не находится, убирать "ошибка", и смотреть уже англоязычные варианты.

Comment: лучший вариант использовать дебагер и смотреть что происходит в вашей программе в конкретный момент времени, в какой переменной что хранится и так выявить можно большинство ошибок

Comment: @had0uken дебагер не поможет, если программа не запустится %))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да но со всякими IndexOutOfBoundsException вполне )

Comment: @had0uken только надо ещё понять что это за зверь такой IndexOutOfBoundsException   а так-то отладка да - хороша, у меня есть даже ответ на эту тему https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/191482   .... но всё же есть случаи, когда оне не поможет или нужно знать доп инфу, чтобы включая её уже использовать отладку

Comment: @Ksenia, а можете добавить пару ошибок, с которыми у Вас были наибольшие трудности? На конкретных примерах легче будет объяснить и понять.

Answer (score 0):

Значит так, ошибки выводятся с указанием  текста ошибки. Вот этот текст нужно копировать и вставлять в Гугл.

К примеру если выпадает `Exception` то надо смотреть `getMessage()`. Обычно в стэктрейсе выводятся сообщения обошибке. Всегда надо искать главную ошибку в стэке. Она может быть либо внизу либо вверху. В зависимости как выдаётся логгером.

Копируем сообщение об ошибке и смотрим где ее исправляли. Возможно на этом сайте. Поэтому можно прямиком заходить на поиск.