# не срабатывает часть кода в цикле for "&& min % 10 == 0"

Tags: java, for

public class Time {

```
static void time() {   //показ времени в формате чч:мм:cc
    for (int hour = 0; hour < 6; hour++) {
        for (int min = 0; min < 60; min++) {
            if (hour > 1 && min % 10 == 0) { //часть про минуты не срабатывает!
                break;
            }
            for (int sec = 0; sec < 60; sec++) {
                if (sec*hour > min) { //это тоже не срабатывает
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    time();
    System.out.println(10 % 10); //пример числа кратного десяти
    //значит в цикле должно было остановить на 1 часу 10 минуте, а он продолжил до 2 часов

}
```

}

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: добавь перед break вывод часов и минут и узнаешь, что там на самом деле работает или не работает.

Comment: *должно было остановить на 1 часу 10 минуте*.  У тебя условие  `if (hour > 1`, как он остановит, если часов 1?

Comment: Я не автор. Это копия кода из лекции. Просто я считаю что часть "&& min % 10 == 0" не рабочая. Если её убрать ничего не меняется. Странно что лектор не увидел что она не работает.