# Не могу понять почему не выводит результат. Не пойму в чем ошибка

Tags: java, компилятор

i

```
Import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    
    public class Main {
        private static Employee[] employees = new Employee[10];
        private static Employee employee;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Employee[] employees = new Employee[10];
            Employee e1 = new Employee("Ольга", "Олеговна", "Спицына", 1, 200);
            Employee e2 = new Employee("Виктори", "Игоревна", "Матыш", 1, 100);
            Employee e3 = new Employee("Елена", "Ботсовна", "Бабич", 1, 300);
            Employee e4 = new Employee("Светлана", "Васильевна", "Берестнева", 1, 400);
            Employee e5 = new Employee("Алексадр", "Юрьевич", "Попов", 1, 500);
            Employee e6 = new Employee("Аллексей", "Иванович", "Иванов", 1, 600);
            Employee e7 = new Employee("Леонид", "Ботсович", "Евглевский", 1, 700);
            Employee e8 = new Employee("Ольга", "Ивановна", "Воз", 1, 800);
            Employee e9 = new Employee("Таитьяна", "Леонидовна", "Петрова", 1, 900);
            Employee e10 = new Employee("Дмитрий", "Александрович", "Решетников", 1, 50);
    
            employees[0] = e1;
            employees[1] = e2;
            employees[2] = e3;
            employees[3] = e4;
            employees[4] = e5;
            employees[5] = e6;
            employees[6] = e7;
            employees[7] = e8;
            employees[8] = e9;
            employees[9] = e10;
    
            ArrayList<Employee> e = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }
        }
    
        public static void Employees() {
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                System.out.println(employee);
            }
        }
    
        public static void fullName() {
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                System.out.println(employee.getSurname());
            }
        }
    
        public static int calculatorTotalSalary() {
            int sum = 0;
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                sum += employee.getSalary();
            }
            return sum;
        }
    
        public static Employee minSalary() {
            Employee result = employees[0];
            int minimalSalary = employees[0].getSalary();
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                if (employee.getSalary() < minimalSalary) {
                    minimalSalary = employee.getSalary();
                    result = employee;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    
        public static Employee maxSalary() {
            Employee result = employees[0];
            int maxSalary = employees[0].getSalary();`введите сюда код`
            for (Employee employee : employees) {
                if (employee.getSalary() > maxSalary) {
                    maxSalary = employee.getSalary();
                }
                result = employee;
            }
            return result;
        }
    
        public static float averageSalary() {
            return calculatorTotalSalary() / (float) employees.length;
        }
    
    
    }
public class Employee {
    private static int counter = 0;
    private final String name;
    private final String lastname;
    private final String surname;
    private int department;
    private int salary;
    private final Integer id;


    // Геттеры
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public int getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public static int getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    // Сеттеры

    public void setDepartment(int department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Employee(String name, String lastname, String surname, int department, int salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.department = department;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.id = counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' + ", surname='" + surname + '\'' + ", department=" + department + ", salary=" + salary + ", id=" + id + '}';
    }


    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Начните с того, что опишите, что этот код должен делать по вашей задумке/плану. И что он в реальности делает.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде три ошибки:

- первый импорт у вас с заглавной буквы, пропишите его с маленькой буквы:      `import java.util.ArrayList;`
- в методе      `public static Employee maxSalary()`  у вас вставлен просто текст, без комментария, его надо удалить (*введите сюда код*)
- второй класс у вас с модификатором public, в одном файле у вас не может быть два класса с этимм модификатором, поэтому у класса      `public class Employee`  уберите модификатор:       `class Employee`