# Почему выскакивает ошибка ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

В методе слияния mergeArrays в условии сравнения выскакивает ошибка ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Почему?

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] commamds =
                {{45, 31, 24, 22, 20, 17, 14, 13, 12, 10},
                        {31, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1},
                        {51, 30, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 2, 1}};

        int[] common = mergeArrays(commamds[0], commamds[1], commamds[2]);
        for (int i = 0; i < common.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(common[i] + " ");
        }

    }

    public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C){
        int[] res = new int[A.length+B.length+C.length];
        int ia =0,ib = 0,ic =0, ires =0;
        while(ia< A.length||ib< B.length||ic< C.length){
            if(ia==A.length&& ib==B.length){
                res[ires] = C[ic];
                ic++;
            }else if(ia == A.length&&ic == C.length){
                res[ires] = B[ib];
                ib++;
            }else if(ib == B.length&& ic == C.length){
                res[ires] = A[ia];
                ia++;
            }else if(A[ia]>=B[ib] && A[ia]>=C[ic]){**//здесь ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.Не пойму где ошибка.**
                res[ires] = A[ia];
                ia++;
            }else if(B[ib]>=A[ia]&&B[ib]>=C[ic]){
                res[ires] = B[ib];
                ib++;
            }else{
                res[ires] = C[ic];
                ic++;
                ires++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Потому что превысил предел длины массива....... где и как - используй отладку чтобы выяснить ↑↑↑

Comment: Я понимаю, что это за ошибка. И дебаг делал. Но разобраться не смог. Потому что ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException выскакивает на строке. else if(A[ia]>=B[ib] && A[ia]>=C[ic])

Comment: ну вот смотри что у тебя в ia  и ib и ic  и почему там значения больше чем длина массива A, B или С  соответственно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы в представленном алгоритме слияния трех массивов необходимо добавить проверки на выход индексов `ia, ib, ic` за пределы соответствующих входных массивов `A, B, C`.  Также следует отдельно рассматривать случаи, когда индексы корректны для всех трёх массивов или хотя бы один из массивов был обработан полностью (и соответствующий индекс достиг допустимого максимума).

Также в представленном алгоритме есть проблема с некорректным инкрементом индекса `ires` в результирующем массиве.

Возможная реализация (с циклом `for` вместо `while`):

```java
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {
    int[] res = new int[A.length + B.length + C.length];
    
    for (int ia = 0, ib = 0, ic = 0, ires = 0; ires < res.length; ires++) {
        if (ia < A.length && ib < B.length && ic < C.length) {
            // искать в трёх массивах
            if (A[ia] >= B[ib]) {
                if (A[ia] >= C[ic]) {
                    res[ires] = A[ia++];
                } else {
                    res[ires] = C[ic++];
                }
            } else if (B[ib] >= C[ic]) {
                res[ires] = B[ib++];
            } else {
                res[ires] = C[ic++];
            }
        } else if (ia == A.length) {
            // искать в B и C
            if (ib == B.length) {
                res[ires] = C[ic++];
            } else if (ic == C.length) {
                res[ires] = B[ib++];
            } else if (B[ib] >= C[ic]) {
                res[ires] = B[ib++];
            } else {
                res[ires] = C[ic++];
            }
        } else if (ib == B.length) {
            // искать в A и C
            if (ic == C.length || A[ia] >= C[ic]) {
                res[ires] = A[ia++];
            } else {
                res[ires] = C[ic++];
            }
        } else if (B[ib] >= A[ia]) {
            res[ires] = B[ib++];
        } else {
            res[ires] = A[ia++];
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Проблема решается. Правда я до этого не знал, что res[ires] = A[ia++]; - это тоже самое, что res[ires] = A[ia]; ia++;