# Не выполняется последний метод в классе main

Tags: java, калькулятор

Сделал простой калькулятор, но последний метод в классе `main` не выполняется, т. е. не считает.

Есть подозрение, что накосячил в методах:

```
package program;
import  java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator2 {
public static int getNumber1() { //метод для 1 числа
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number1 = scanner.nextInt();
    return number1;
     }
    public static int getNumber2() { //метод для 2 числа
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number2 = scanner.nextInt();
    return number2;
   }
    public static char getSymbol() { // метод для арифметической операции
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    char symbol = scanner.next().charAt(0);
    return symbol;
    }
    public static int total(int a, int b, char c){
   a = getNumber1();
   b = getNumber2();
   c = getSymbol();
    int totalMath;
   if (c == '+') {
       System.out.println(a + b);
   }
   else if (c == '-') {
       System.out.println(a - b);
   }
   else if (c == '*') {
       totalMath = a * b;
   }
   else if (c == '/') {
       totalMath = a / b;
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("Пожалуйста, проверьте правильность введенных данных");
   }

    totalMath = total(a, b, c);
   return totalMath;
     }


     public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println("Введите число: ");
       int number1 = getNumber1();
        System.out.println("Ваше число: " + number1 + ". Введите второе число: ");
       int number2 = getNumber2();
        System.out.println("Ваше число: " + number2 + " Введите операцию, которую 
     хотите 
        совершить между двумя введенными числами. Пришлите \"+\", \"-\", \"*\" или 
    \"/\"");
    char symbol = getSymbol();
    int calculator = total(number1, number2, symbol);
    System.out.print("Отлично! Вы ввели знак " + "\"" + symbol + "\"" + ". Ваш 
результат: " + calculator);



  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в методе метод total(), перезаписываете переданные аргументы. Уберите повторный вызов методов. Плюс у вас получилась рекурсия.:

```
public static int total(int a, int b, char c){
 a = getNumber1(); // перезапись переданного значения a
 b = getNumber2(); // перезапись переданного значения b
 c = getSymbol();  // перезапись переданного значения c
 //....
 totalMath = total(a, b, c); // рекурсивный вызов
 return totalMath;
}
```

Также для поиска подобных проблем, используйте режим отладки - [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-java)

Comment: Спасибо за обратную связь) Перезапись удалил, но когда убрал рекурсивный метод, IDE стала ругаться, что в начале переменную totalMath нужно инициализировать после объявления. Простите меня, я тупой

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо еще раз за обратную связь!) Крепкого здоровья и исполнения желаний и мечтаний)

Comment: @Темныйвластелин У вас просто мало опыта, все совершали подобные ошибки. Изучите процесс отладки, он очень помогает в работе, и вы буквально увидите как выполняется программа.