# Почему kieServices в файле классе Main имеет значение null?

Tags: java, maven, drools

Почему kieServices в файле классе Main имеет значение null? Используется `maven` и `drools` в `IDE Eclipse`, суть приложения: Приложение для управления бизнес-правилами на основе `Drools`.

Все необходимые библиотеки `Drools` я поставил. Ниже `pom.xml` .

**Описание ошибки:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot invoke "org.kie.api.KieServices.getKieClasspathContainer()" because "kieServices" is null
    at com.javainuse.main.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

**проект находится [здесь](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/ZhKsfPgvV1lV1w).**

Код проекта:

**main.java:**

```
package com.javainuse.main;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

import com.javainuse.model.Product;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kieSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();
        Product product = new Product("soda", 5, true, 2);
        kieSession.insert(product);
        kieSession.fireAllRules();
        kieSession.dispose();
    }
}
```

**Product.java:**

```
package com.javainuse.model;

public class Product {
    public String name;
    public int quantity;
    public boolean onPromotion;
    public int emptyBottles;

    public Product(String name, int quantity, boolean onPromotion, int emptyBottles) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.onPromotion = onPromotion;
        this.emptyBottles = emptyBottles;
    }

}
```

**Rules.drl:**

```
package com.rule

import com.javainuse.model.Product


rule "Check promotion"
    when
        $p : Product(name == "soda", onPromotion == true)
    then
        System.out.println("The product is on promotion!");
    end


rule "Check number of bottles"
    when
        $p : Product(name == "soda", quantity >= 2)
    then
        System.out.println("You can exchange two empty bottles for one new bottle!");
    end


rule "Check number of empty bottles"
    when
        $p : Product(name == "soda", emptyBottles >= 2)
    then
        System.out.println("You can exchange two empty bottles for one new bottle!");
    end
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
  <artifactId>lab1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
          <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
          <version>7.59.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопросов: [Что такое Null Pointer Exception и как его исправить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511085/); [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/)

Comment: @Nowhere Man неправильно сформулировал вопрос, изменил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас используется новая версия JDK, которая *сразу* указывает в сообщении об ошибке, что экземпляр класса `KieServices kieServices` является `null` в методе `main` на строке №13, и поэтому вызов метода `getKieClasspathContainer()` для данной переменной невозможен.

Экземпляр сервиса у вас создаётся в строке:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get(); // !!!!!
// ...
}
```

то есть, проблема в том, что у вас вызов `KieServices.Factory.get()` возвращает `null`.

Запрос в гугл: [kieservices.factory.get() returns null](https://www.google.com/search?q=kieservices.factory.get%28%29+returns+null) возвращает несколько ссылок на аналогичную проблему на основном StackOverflow:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основные решения для этой проблемы указаны по ссылке [Drools 7.4.1 kieservices.factory.get() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556233/):

1. Необходимо добавить зависимость в `pom.xml` на компилятор Drools:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Также может понадобиться модифицировать файл конфигурации `drools-core kie.conf` и добавить в него строки:

```
org.kie.api.KieServices = org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieServicesImpl
org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService = org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl
```