# Как проверять участок кода в проектах C#/Java без компиляции всего проекта?

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio, intellij-idea, тестирование

Например, в проекте на `Python` можно создать файл `Test.py` и запускать там несколько строчек кода, которые хочется проверить, индивидуально без компиляции всего проекта и не выходя из проекта.

В проектах `Java`/`C#`, насколько я понимаю, отдельный файл вроде `Test.cs` не может быть запущен как самостоятельная единица. Закрывать в `IDE` текущий проект и создавать новый (тестовый) проект кажется не очень удобным способом.

**P.S.**

1. Я только учусь писать код и иногда просто сомневаюсь, правильно ли использую конструкции языка;
2. используемые программы - `IntelliJ IDEA`, `Visual Studio 2022`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-java)

Comment: Может нужно что-то типа RoslynPad? (https://roslynpad.net/)

Comment: А про c#: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701429/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c?rq=1)

Comment: _В проектах Java/C#, насколько я понимаю, отдельный файл вроде "Test.cs" не может быть запущен как самостоятельная единица._  Неверное представление, можно запускать и отдельный тест в файле, и набор тестов в одном файле, и полный набор тестов во всех файлах при билде проекта.

Comment: Visual Studio позволяет открывать одновременно больше одного проекта. Может быть запущен не просто отдельный файл, а отдельный тест из файла.

Comment: Можно запустить второй экземпляр Студии (желательно памяти в компе иметь побольше). Можно создать ещё один проект в этом же решении и переключаться между ними (делать стартовым). Можно использовать [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В VS и в Rider есть окно **C# Interactive**.

В Rider см. меню <kbd>Tools, C# Interactive</kbd>.

В Visual Studio см. меню <kbd>View, Other Windows, C# Interactive</kbd>.

Там можно вводить отдельные конструкции C# и проверять, как они работают. Можно подключать отдельные пакеты (сборки) с помощью [директивы `#r`](https://tomaskohl.com/code/2020-02-11/dotnet-interactive-using-nuget-packages/).

Чтобы не писать полные пути к классам, можно использовать конструкцию `using`. Можно выполнить в окне кусок существующего кода: надо выделить код и отправить его (send) в C# Interactive (работает что-то из <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd> или <kbd>Ctrl+\</kbd>, также работает через меню).