# Что исправить? Rest Java

Tags: java, spring, rest

Хочу сделать `get` и `post` запросы через `RestController`:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RestController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public ResponseEntity addUser(@RequestParam String name,
                                  @RequestParam String surname,
                                  @RequestParam String login,
                                  @RequestParam String phone_number,
                                  @RequestParam String email,
                                  @RequestParam String password,
                                  @RequestParam Date birthday) {
        User user = new User(name, surname, login, phone_number, email, bcrypt(password), birthday);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Пользователь добавлен");
    }
```

Нужно получить ответ в формате json из метода `addUser`, который возвращает `ResponseEntity.ok("Пользователь добавлен")`,
а ответ получается:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2023-12-24T10:01:00.156+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/api/addUser"
}
```

Аналогично с `get`-запросом:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/get/{email}", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity sendToken(@PathVariable(value = "email") String email) {
    System.out.println(email);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("true");
}
```

В ответе приходит:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2023-12-24T10:25:15.528+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/get/email@bk.ru"
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701409/)

Comment: По представленным фрагментам кода тяжело что-то вам подсказать.  В частности, в методе `sendToken` (GET-запросе), практически нечему падать с 500 ошибкой.

Comment: Если писать как String: ``` @PostMapping("/addUser")
   //...... return "redirect:/verify";``` - то строку он возращает, но это просто @Controller, а не @RestController

Answer (score 0):

Этот метод возвращается корректно:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/all-users", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    public ResponseEntity getAllUsers() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userRepository.findAll());
    }
```

А с остальными, представленными выше, какая то беда