# Почему мы не можем "зайти" в метод println() в дебаггере?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В hello-world программе на выражении `System.out.println("Simple message");` ставим точку остановки. Во время отладки мы не можем посмотреть на логику работы метода println(), как мы это могли бы сделать с любым пользовательским методом. Теоретически, классы, поставляемые в JDK (наподобие System) ничем не отличаются от пользовательских, и мы могли бы написать и отладить их сами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так происходит?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Simple message");
    }
}
```

Comment: А какие клавиши ты нажимаешь "для входа"?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский. Использую IntellijIdea. JDK - corretto1.8. Cтавлю точку останова на выражении `System.out.println("Simple message");`. Запускаю "Debug Main.main();".

Comment: Но ведь этого не достаточно. Во время дебага можно управлять ещё другими клавишами: "без входа в метод" и для "со входом в метод" и т.д.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701413/191482

Comment: Дебажу только с заходом в метод

Comment: Поставил brakepoint внутри самого метода println(), и дебаггер попал туда. Если ставить brakepoint на выражении `System.out.println("Simple message");`, то дебаггер пропускает эту конструкцию.

Comment: Используйте Force Step Into https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#force-step-into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При отладке идея пропускает некоторые методы. Поэтому чтобы зайти в них, нужно использовать Force Step Into. Подробности тут: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#force-step-into

> Some methods (for example, methods of standard Java classes like System) are skipped by Step into as you normally might not need to debug them. This list can be fine-tuned on the Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping page of the Settings dialog